# How to customise date format in ngx-mydatepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, datepicker

I use ngx-mydatepicker directive https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker.

I wanna get such date format: 21 January, 2018, but in this datepicker it isn't supported.

As I understood, if change **monthLabels** from Jan to January, I get necessary result, however, this action also change month labels in inline calendar and they may not fit fully.

I tried to use pipe. And date.formatted was changed as I wish, but was not displayed in browser.

```
date = {
  date: {year: 2018, month: 1, day: 30}
  epoc: 1517259600
  formatted: "30 January, 2018"
  jsdate: Tue Jan 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300
}
```

*In component*

```
option = {
monthLabels: <IMyMonthLabels>{
  1: 'Jan',
  2: 'Feb',
  3: 'Mar',
  4: 'Apr',
  5: 'May',
  6: 'Jun',
  7: 'Jul',
  8: 'Aug',
  9: 'Sep',
  10: 'Oct',
  11: 'Nov',
  12: 'Dec'
},
dateFormat: 'dd mmm, yyyy',
```

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" name="date"
ngx-mydatepicker 
[ngModel]="date | dateFormat" 
(dateChanged)="date=$event" 
[options]="options"
#dp="ngx-mydatepicker">
```

*Pipe*

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})

export class DateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(date: any): any {
    if (!date) { return {}; }
    const monthNames = [
      'January', 'February', 'March',
      'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
      'August', 'September', 'October',
      'November', 'December'
    ];
    date.formatted = date.jsdate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[date.jsdate.getMonth()] + ', ' + date.jsdate.getFullYear();
    return date;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is necessery to write [ngModel], and (dateChanged) or (ngModelChange) instead two-way binding [(ngModel)]:

   ```
   <input type="text" name="date" ngx-mydatepicker [ngModel]="date" dateChanged)="onDateChange($event)" [options]="options" #dp="ngx-mydatepicker">
   ```
2. In function **onDateChange()** we can customise date format as you wish. For example:

   ```
   changeFormat(event: IMyDateModel): void{
   const monthNames = [
     'January', 'February', 'March',
     'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
     'August', 'September', 'October',
     'November', 'December'
   ];
   event.formatted = event.jsdate.getDate() + ' ' +     monthNames[event.jsdate.getMonth()] + ', ' + event.jsdate.getFullYear();
   ```

   }
3. Done. Now you have format *22 January, 2018*